# Trying to understand it better. What is the difference between these two implementations?

Tags: c++, vector, maps

These two example both work and do the same thing.
I'm just trying to get what is the difference between them in terms of optimization, speed and overall. Which approach is better and why? Thanks in advance.

First example:

```
std::map<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double>> data
printMap(&data);

...

void printMap(std::map<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double>> *p_data){

    for(std::map<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double>>::iterator itr = p_data->begin(); itr != p_data->end(); ++itr){

        for(auto it = itr->first.begin(); it != itr->first.end(); ++it){
                std::cout << *it << std::endl;
            }
        for(auto it2 = itr->second.begin(); it2 != itr->second.end(); ++it2){
                std::cout << *it2 << std::endl;
            }
    }
}
```

Second example:

```
std::map<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double>> data;
printMapRef(data);

void printMapRef(std::map<std::vector<int>,std::vector<double>> &data){
    for(std::map<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double>>::iterator itr = data.begin(); itr != data.end(); ++itr){

        std::vector<int> tempVecInt = (*itr).first;
        std::vector<double> tempVecDouble = (*itr).second;

        for (int i = 0; i < tempVecInt.size(); i++){
            std::cout << tempVecInt.at(i) << " ";
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < tempVecDouble.size(); j++){
            std::cout << tempVecDouble.at(j) << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The second one is preferrable, since this enables some compiler checks in the calling function. Also the use of a reference clearly indicates that (a dereferenced) null must not be passed which is something that is could only be solved via documentation in the first snippet which may or may not be looked at by the user closely.

Comment: Note that imho you should make the parameter a ref/pointer to const and use ranged for loops + structured binding for much simpler code: `void printMapRef(std::map<std::vector<int>,std::vector<double>> const &data){ for(auto& [key, value] : data) { for (auto k : key) { std::cout << k << " ";} for (auto v : value) { std::cout << v << " "; } } }`

Comment: The main reason to pass a pointer instead of a reference as an argument is that you expect to be able to do something meaningful if `nullptr` is passed, because `nullptr` is a valid pointer but there's no such thing as a null reference. Since `printMap` doesn't actually work sensibly if you pass it a null pointer (it immediately invokes undefined behavior by dereferencing `p_data`), IMO `printMapRef` is preferable.

Comment: Thank you guys! It's getting more clear.

Answer (score 5):

The obvious difference is that the first iterates through the vectors that are in the map, while the second creates copies of the vectors in the map, then iterates through the copies.

The second also uses `.at` to index into each vector, which checks that the index is within bounds (and throws an exception if it isn't).

Especially if the vectors are large, those could easily make the second significantly slower than the first.

Most of the other differences are mostly syntactic. Personally I don't particularly like the syntax of the iterator-based loop, but iterators vs. indices is unlikely to make any real difference in speed or anything like that.

For what little it's worth, my own preference would be to pass the map in by (`const`) reference and use range-based `for` loops. I'd also at least consider using a function to print out the contents of each vector, since you have two loops that should be essentially identical.